# Why does the compilation fail with error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c, structure

**Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct s
{
    int a;
    struct x
    {
        int b;
    }*p;
};
int main()
{
    struct s *a;
    a=(struct s *)malloc(sizeof(struct s) * 10);
    a->p=(struct x)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:-  In function 'main': 16:41: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested      a->p=(struct x)malloc(sizeof(struct x));                                          ^**

Comment: `=(struct x)malloc` -> `=(struct x*)malloc`. Or just don't cast (e.g.: `a->p = malloc(sizeof(struct x));`

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Third the "just don't cast."  [Really, just don't](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, as in physics, a scalar type is a type that just has a single magnitude. Integer types, floating point types and pointer types are considered to be scalar types. `struct`s are not scalar types.

This line

```
 a->p=(struct x)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
```

attempts to cast the result of a malloc which is a pointer (a `void*` in fact and thus a scalar, to a struct which is not. `a->p` is also a pointer, having type `struct s*` so what the error message means is that your cast forgets the `*` that makes the target type a pointer type. i.e. this is what it should be:

```
 a->p=(struct x*)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
```

Actually, in C, as opposed to C++ you don't need to cast `void*` to other pointer types, so it is better just to write

```
 a->p=malloc(sizeof(struct x));
```

The main reason for this is that if you forget to include `stdlib.h` which is where the prototype for `malloc` comes from, the compiler assumes that `malloc` returns `int` which is a disaster if a pointer cannot be represented as an `int`. For example, modern 64 bit compilers often have 32 bit `int` and 64 bit pointers. Putting the cast in silences the warning that the compiler is assuming `malloc` returns `int` because you forgot `stdlib.h`

One final improvement: you can take `sizeof` of an object even if it doesn't exist yet so

```
a->p=malloc(sizeof *(a->p));
```

The compiler often knows the size of the thing a->p points to and so sets the sizeof to the right number as long as it knows the size (see "incomplete types" for an exception). Now you can modify the type of `a->p` without having to fix all the `malloc`s.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. It appears that a scalar is useful term. Have an upvote from a humbled cat.

Comment: Although I can't resist saying that you should remove "as in physics".

Comment: @Bathsheba "scalar type" is an official term as used in C11, it is defined as "arithmetic and pointer types" (see 6.2.5 post 21).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid type-mismatches, allocations should follow the canonical way of

```
a = malloc(10 * sizeof(*a));
a->p = malloc(1 * sizeof(*a->p));
```

i.e. always referencing the variable being assigned to in the `sizeof`. Note how short this is. **Note how this auto-adapts when the type of `a` changes**. You could even drop the parentheses around the `sizeof` operand and the multiplication by 1.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you're attempting to assign a `struct x` (casted from `void *`) to a `struct x *`.  You can't assign a non-pointer to a pointer.

You can avoid this by using the correct cast:

```
a->p=(struct x *)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
```

Or better yet remove the cast entirely, since you can freely cast between a `void *` and any non-function pointer without one:

```
a=malloc(sizeof(struct s) * 10);
a->p=malloc(sizeof(struct x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing asterix.   If the type conversion is really necessary, the statement

```
a->p=(struct x)malloc(sizeof(struct x));   // struct x is not a pointer
```

should actually be

```
a->p=(struct x *)malloc(sizeof(struct x));
```

Of course, as others have said in comments, the type conversion is inadvisable.   It would also be advisable to not name the types being `malloc()`ed in the parameter of `sizeof` so the two statements in your function would be

```
a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 10);
a->p = malloc(sizeof(*(a->p)));
```

It would also be advisable to check the result of each call of `malloc()` before using it, since `malloc()` returns `NULL` when it fails.

Note:  if your C compiler is really a C++ compiler, a conversion of the result of `malloc()` would be needed.   However, in standard C, the conversion is not required, and is actively discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo that originates from the inadvisable practice of casting `malloc` on the right of an assignment<sup>1</sup>.

Also you should check the return value of `malloc`, especially before using the pointer to member operator `->`.

So I'd rather see something on the lines of

```
if (a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 10)){
    if (a->p = malloc(sizeof(*(a->p)))){
        // Everything is allocated.
        // ToDo - code here
        free(a->p);
    }
    free(a);
}
```

(Note that in the evaluation of `sizeof(*(a->p))` the compiler must **not** actually do any dereferencing, so it doesn't matter if `a` is valid or `a->p` is valid.)

---

<sup>1</sup>See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score -1):

You should try 
a->p=(struct x*)malloc(sizeof(struct x));

Comment: Nah, you should't cast.